# neo4j: how to return paths with labels of nodes and relations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My query returns paths:

```
match path = ...
return path
```

but nodes and relationships labels are missing. How can i add them?

```
return path, labels(path)
```

gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best thing i managed to achieve is

```
match path = ...
return path, extract (x in rels(path) | type(x)) as types, extract (n in nodes(path) | labels(n)) as labels
```

it allows one to reconstruct the whole path structure on the backend. although still contains a lot of duplication

Answer (score 1):

You can use named nodes in the whole path. Then sum the labels from each named node (`labels(a) + labels(b)`). After it you can remove the duplications with `UNWIND` and `collect distinct`. Also, you can do the same thing to get the relationship types, but using the [relationships()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) function.

```
match path = (a)-->(b)
with path, labels(a) + labels(b) as labels, relationships(path) as relationships
unwind(labels) as label
unwind(relationships) as relationship
return path, collect(distinct label) as labels, collect(distinct type(relationship)) as relationships
```

Comment: none of the solutions return labels (types) from relations

Comment: @piotrek edited the answer. I used the second solution to add an extra column to return the relationship types. Please, take a look.